# Graphic alignment

Tags: positioning

I want to position three graphics next to each other, so that they are aligned at the top line. I used \begin{minipage}, but that does't work like I want it to...

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[t]
\includegraphics[width=2cm,angle=90]{test1}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]
\includegraphics[width=2.5cm,angle=90]{test2}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{test3}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 6):

`\begin{minipage}[t]` sets the first line/top element to the base line. In your case its the image. However the images have different heights.
An invisible top element helps, e.g. `\vspace{0pt}`:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[t]{2cm}
  \vspace{0pt}
  \includegraphics[width=2cm,angle=90]{test1}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{2.5cm}
  \vspace{0pt}
  \includegraphics[width=2.5cm,angle=90]{test2}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{2cm}
  \vspace{0pt}
  \includegraphics[width=2cm]{test3}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

The width is specified twice, as argument for `minipage` and for the image. This redundancy can be removed by environment `varwidth` of package `varwidth`, for instance:

```
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
  \vspace{0pt}
  \includegraphics[width=2cm,angle=90]{test1}
\end{varwidth}
```

An alternative is `\raisebox`. It can be used to move the top of the image to
the base line:

```
\raisebox{-\height}{%
  \includegraphics[width=2cm,angle=90]{test1}%
}
```

(Don't forget to comment the line ends, otherwise they are adding spaces
in horizontal mode.)

Full example with rules instead of images:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{2cm}
    \vspace{0pt}   
    \rule{2cm}{1cm}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{2.5cm}
    \vspace{0pt}
    \rule{2.5cm}{3cm}  
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{2cm}
    \vspace{0pt}
    \rule{2cm}{2cm}    
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth}
    \vspace{0pt}
    \rule{2cm}{1cm}
  \end{varwidth}
  \begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth}
    \vspace{0pt}
    \rule{2.5cm}{3cm}
  \end{varwidth}
  \begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth}
    \vspace{0pt}
    \rule{2cm}{2cm}
  \end{varwidth}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \raisebox{-\height}{%
    \rule{2cm}{1cm}%
  }
  \raisebox{-\height}{%
    \rule{2.5cm}{3cm}%
  }
  \raisebox{-\height}{%
    \rule{2cm}{2cm}%
  }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

And finally a macro `\topalign` follows. Its implementation is based
on `\halign` (TeX primitive, which is used in environment `tabular`).
The cell contents is put into a temporary box and lowered to the base line.
The first optional parameter specifies the horizontal space between
the aligned elements.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}

\newcommand{\topalign}[2][0.5em]{%
  \leavevmode
  \vbox{%
    \setlength{\tabskip}{#1}%
    \halign{%
      &%
      \begin{lrbox}{0}%
        \ignorespaces##\unskip
      \end{lrbox}%
      \lower\ht0\copy0 %
      \cr
      #2%
      \crcr
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \topalign{
    \rule{2cm}{1cm}
    &
    \rule{2.5cm}{3cm}
    &
    \rule{2cm}{2cm}
  }%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `adjustbox` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=2cm,angle=90,valign=T]{example-image.pdf}
\includegraphics[width=2.5cm,angle=90,valign=T]{example-image-a.pdf}
\includegraphics[width=2cm,valign=T]{example-image-b.pdf}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]